# Python tkinter get the value of multiple checkbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox, customtkinter

For my tkinter/customtkinter gui, i have several checkbox and i want to automatically see if they are checked or not.

All my checkbox have a name like "box0", "box1", "box2", etc.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bbez.png)

After that, i have a button, and when you click, i call my function named "check"

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/COSP7.png)

My function is like this, it check if the box0 is checked of not:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dO3z.png)

But i don't want to copy paste and type 4 times the same code, i want to automatize it, with something like that:

```
def check():
     for i in range(4):
          if box+i == 1: 
               print(f"Box{i} is checked")
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: please don't post images of code.

Comment: Loop over a list of the checkboxes: `[box0, box1, box2, ...]`.  Or better yet, put all of the checkboxes in a list to start with, rather than assigning them to individual names.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all of your checkboxes in a list and then iterate through the list to check if the checkbox is checked.

For example:

```
box0 = CTkCheckBox(app)
box1 = CTkCheckBox(app)
box2 = CTkCheckBox(app)
box3 = CTkCheckBox(app)
checkboxes = [box0, box1, box2, box3]

# you can also define your checkboxes in the list
# checkboxes = [CTkCheckBox(app) for _ in range(4)]

def check():
    for i, checkbox in enumerate(checkboxes):
        if checkbox.get() == 1:
           print(f"box{i} is checked")
            

button = CTkButton(app, text="install", command=check)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list with labels and a list of variables for the check boxes

```
import tkinter as tk
labels=['Python','PHP','HTML']
variables=[]
def test():
    for x in range(len(variables)):
        value=variables[x].get()
        if value==0:
            print(labels[x]+","+"is not selected!")
        else:
            print(labels[x]+","+"is selected!")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")

for x in range(len(labels)):
    variables.append(tk.IntVar(value=0))
    c=tk.Checkbutton(root,text=labels[x],variable=variables[x])
    c.grid(row=1,column=x+1)
B = tk.Button(root, text ="test", command = test)
B.grid(row=2)
root.mainloop()
```